# How to get the authentication status from the last PAM module run

Tags: authentication, c, pam

If I have the following PAM stack:

```
auth required default_pam.so
auth requisite my_custom_pam.so
....
```

How do you obtain the authentication status from the last/previous PAM module run for use in your own custom PAM authentication module (in for example the `pam_sm_authenticate` function)?

Answer (score 1):

First, keep in mind that it is rather unconventional to have your module's code logic change according to other modules' results: this is usually done by using control flags, such as `required` and `requisite`, which control which modules get called, in which situations (i.e. according to the current chain status, previous modules' results). With that in mind, you could imagine adapting your module's behaviour this way:

```
auth [success=1] default_pam.so
auth [success=done default=die] my_custom_pam.so default_failed
auth requisite my_custom_pam.so
```

This chain has the following logic:

- If the default module succeeds, mark it as validated (implied by `success=1`) and skip 1 module. The chain reaches `my_custom_pam` called with no argument, which will have to succeed (`requisite`).
- If the default module fails, don't skip anything. The chain reaches `my_custom_pam`, called with an argument, `default_failed`. The chain will stop after this module (`done` or `die`) and it will determine the overall result.

Here, the key element is the argument passed to `my_custom_pam`. By checking `argc` and `argv` in your `pam_sm_authenticate` routine, you'll be able to adapt your logic according to the current chain status.